# Facing issue with NSPredicate

Tags: ios, nsarray, nspredicate

In my project below is the Dictionary, i have a list of dictionaries which i am trying to get the same value based on predicate but i am not getting the value.

```
    NSPredicate* searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K CONTAINS[c] %@)",@"**equipArray.equipmentName**",textField.text];

    NSLog(@"searchPredicate %@",searchPredicate);

    NSArray* searchList = [list filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate];
```

But i am not able to get the list. can anyone help me ?

```
    {
    equipArray =         (
                    {
            equipmentIcon = "outside.png";
            equipmentName = Outside;
        },
                    {
            equipmentIcon = "steps.png";
            equipmentName = Steps;
        },
                    {
            equipmentIcon = "partner.png";
            equipmentName = Partner;
        }
    );
    exId = 4;
    exeName = "Fireman Carry";
    exerciseAudioCue = "DG Fighting Fit-exercise_audio_test.mp3";
    exerciseDescription = "Proin gravida nibh vel velit auctor aliquet. Aenean sollicitudin, lorem quis bibendum auctor, nisi elit consequat ipsum, nec sagittis sem nibh id elit. Duis sed odio sit amet nibh vulputate cursus a sit amet mauris. Morbi accumsan ipsum velit. Nam nec tellus a odio tincidunt auctor a ornare odio. Sed non  mauris vitae erat consequat auctor eu in elit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris in erat justo. Nullam ac urna eu felis dapibus condimentum sit amet a augue. Sed non neque elit. Sed ut imperdiet nisi. Proin condimentum fermentum nunc. Etiam pharetra, erat sed fermentum feugiat, velit mauris egestas quam, ut aliquam massa nisl quis neque. Suspendisse in orci enim.";
    exerciseType = Stamina;
    imageThumbNail = "firemancarry_thumbnail.png";
    longVideoName = long;
    shortVideoName = small;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `**equipArray.equipmentName**` be `equipArray.equipmentName` simply? Why all those asterisks?

Comment: Yes it is equipArray.equipmentName only While pasting here i tried keep bold so got those extra characters i am using equipArray.equipmentName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find elements where *any* `equipmentName` in the `equipArray` contains the
given string, use:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K CONTAINS[c] %@", @"equipArray.equipmentName", textField.text];
```

("CONTAINS" is for string comparison, not to check for containment in an array.)

Comment: @kiri: What is the contents of `textField.text` ?

Comment: content is for search field when click on search button i am passing. just like @"Out" for "Outside" side in dictionary

Comment: NSPredicate* searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (%K CONTAINS[c] %@) OR (%K CONTAINS[c] %@))",@"exeName",textField.text,@"exerciseType",textField.text,@"equipArray.equipmentName",textField.text];
This is the actual predicate using for other items I am getting results well

Answer (score 0):

Use this predicate this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"equipArray.equipmentName =[cd] %@", textField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this,

```
NSPredicate* searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(equipArray.equipmentName CONTAINS[c] %@)",textField.text];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSPredicate *searchPredicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %K == [cd] %@", @"equipArray.equipmentName", @"steps"];
```